# What is the most efficient method of returning the first index in a list of numbers whereby that index matches the number itself?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

Example:

list1 = [1,4,2] ---> would return 2

list2 = [9, 5, 7, 4, 4] ---> would return 4

My current code:

```
def my_function(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] == i:
            return i
    return -1
```

If there is no match, -1 is returned. I am looking for the quickest, fastest-performing method as the lists I'm working with can be very long. My current code works, but I would like to know the most efficient method possible.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to optimize it even more unless you have the ability to change the `list` beforehand.

Comment: If your list isn't sorted, you can't do better than `O(n)`

Comment: You could try `next((i for i, j in enumerate(list) if i == j), None)`, but I doubt that would help very much.  You should probably use `enumerate` in your original code, rather than accessing the list by index.

Comment: You can replace `for i in range(len(list)): if list[i] == i:` with `for i,v in enumerate(list): if v == i;`.

Comment: I strongly advise you never to use `list` as the name of a variable. `list` is [a builtin python class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) and you really don't want to assign something else to the name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` rather than your `range(len(list))` thing:

```
In [20]: def g(lst):
    ...:     for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    ...:         if i == j:
    ...:             return i
    ...:     return -1
    ...:     

In [21]: g(list1)
Out[21]: 2

In [22]: g(list2)
Out[22]: 4

In [23]: g([1,2,3,4])
Out[23]: -1
```

Comment: Any evidence this is more efficient, other than your intuition?

Comment: It is more *Pythonic*, and so more easily maintained and read. Timings often depend on real data sizes so you might want to time one against the other with your real large data.

Comment: I won't argue, this is the implementation I would prefer myself.  But the question wasn't about Pythonic, the question was about efficiency - and you didn't answer it.

Comment: I mentioned that `you` should time it with representative samples of your actual data to determine which you think is more efficient.